# Use .htaccess to redirect old URLs to new URLs, which are moving from a subdirectory to root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an old version of the website in pure html at `/` and I have WordPress (the new website) installed at `/m/`. That's where the files are, but I want it to load at `/`.

So, I want to first make `/m/some-query` to load as `/some-query`.

I think this will work, from what I've read, right?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then secondly, I want to specify a series of URLs: `/old-url-1` to 301 redirect to `/new-url-1`. So that when search engines visit old pages, they are redirected to the new equivalents.

Comment: @anubhava No, the URL structure is changing. I want visits who visit old pages, be directed to the new pages. `/m/` is no longer a factor in the second step.

Comment: But you wrote new website is at `/m/` path

Comment: @anubhava That's only the location of the files on the server.

Comment: Inside `/m/.htaccess` you can use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]` will work but I think WP needs something more in config

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of the old one (or move it to `/old/`) and move the WP one to root?

Comment: @MikeRockett Good idea. I don't have SSH access but should be able to do this from FTP.